Rename and synonymize [pynecone] to [python-reflex]
Current tag: pynecone

Reflex is a library to build full-stack web apps in pure Python.
— README.md | @reflex-dev/reflex

I think this is quite a clear-cut case. The project was renamed from Pynecone to Reflex in 2023. The new tag name has the conventional python- prefix so that it won't be mistaken for reflex (which is about a Haskell library).

Just a thought, maybe the reflex tag should be renamed to haskell-reflex, so it wont be accidentally misused.

There's also at least two questions about a lexer called RE/flex. I don't know what these should be tagged.

@AbdulAzizBarkat One of those isn't actually about RE/flex; the author researched and discovered that it could be an alternate tool for the task, and edited it in. And really, questions don't need to be tagged with everything that could apply.

There appears to be another Python project called Pynecone also. Some of the questions are clearly about Reflex, while others are clearly about the project currently named Pynecone.  This should probably be cleaned up before a rename, ideally by someone who can tell the difference reliably (I identified the one I linked because it links the docs).

@RyanM it seems that both are actually the same, I guess they still have the old site up? (If you open the GitHub link at the top right of the page in the first link it redirects to Reflex's GitHub)

Done.  pynecone is now renamed to python-reflex, and a synonym has been created.
updating post history, 17 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 16 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'python-reflex' doesn't exist, renaming 'pynecone' to 'python-reflex'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [python-reflex] and [pynecone] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
5 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym pynecone -> python-reflex was approved!


Agreed; they are one and the same.
You can tell that the Reflex GitHub repository was renamed from Pynecone by going to the Pynecone website and clicking on the link to their GitHub repository, which uses the URL https://github.com/pynecone-io/pynecone, but then at GitHub redirects that URL to https://github.com/reflex-dev/reflex
The Reflex repo's Readme has this blurb:

Reflex launched in December 2022 with the name Pynecone.
As of February 2024, our hosting service is in alpha! During this time anyone can deploy their apps for free. See our roadmap to see what's planned.

Given that their launched a hosting service in February and it's now currently April, my guess is that they just haven't updated all their website details yet from the old names and URLs.
There's also this blog post announcing the rename back in June of 2023:

We have some exciting news to share about the next stage of our company!
Pynecone is rebranding to Reflex.
Key Changes
Our main website will change from https://pynecone.io to https://reflex.dev.

